# Adding charts using 2 dropdowns and whose values are in a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hello guys I'm new here so excuse me if the format of the question is wrong. Anyway,here I'm trying to create charts based on the change in the dropdowns (2 dropdowns to be specific). I'm getting an error "Method 'ChartType' of object '_Chart' failed" and a blank chart on the sheet.

```
Sub DropDown27_Change()
Dim a As Range, b As Range
Set a = Sheet8.Range("I11")
Set b = Sheet8.Range("K11")
If a.Value = 1 And b.Value = 1 Then
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Top = 10
 ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Left = 10
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumn
 ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("EquityC")
 ActiveChart.HasTitle = False
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `1` Where is the chart? Which Sheet? `2` Where is the Range("EquityC")? Which Sheet? `3` Where is the dropdown? Which sheet?

Comment: 1. I'm trying to make the chart using VBA (I have updated the code above) in sheet23
2. EquityC is in the sheet8
3. Both the dropdowns are in sheet23

Comment: You said you were not getting errors and now i see you are getting errors

Comment: I didnt get any before updating the code. Now that I did an error came up

Comment: Now worries. I see it is sorted now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ChartType instead of `xlColumn` use `xlColumnClustered`

Comment: Its working now. Thanks mate. One more question, right now whenever I click that particular value in the drop down it creates the chart everytime whereas I want it to change only when I change the the value in the dropdown. I hope I explained it well.

Comment: As far i understand you want to update the chart when the dropdown value changes but the line ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select creates the chart everytime, so this needs a modification. You can check if chart exists and don't create but select it in such case  `If (ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)) Is Nothing Then
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 End If
 ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Top = 10
 ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Left = 10
 ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Select
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered`

Comment: 'ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Select ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered'  I'm getting error on this line "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: This code will be in one line `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Select`  and `ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered` will be on the next line

Comment: Same error on line 'ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered'